# How to automatically copy randomly generated text from a website

Tags: script, python, macros

I am not sure how best to ask this, as this my be a multi-pronged question, requiring different avenues of attack and my preconception of the solution is a basic input-function-output scenario. I am a n00b, so to speak, when it comes to scripting-macros-and-other-computer-automated-tasks and figured this might be a good jumping off point. I'm looking for an answer with in limitations, I want to know, but not too much.

Specificity, here's my question;

(Q1) I want my computer to automatically copy randomly generated text from a website and paste it into simple text document as a list. The website is 'Random Word Machine' http://randomwordmachine.com/ and I want to copy the randomly generated English text as a list.

A column-list would be preferred, not a row-list, I'd rather it not be numbered. I'll end up sort the list alphabetically in a spreadsheet.

Limitations;

I am running Windows 7.
I have LibreOffice 4.2, MS Office 2003, AutoHotkey v1.1.14.03, Notepad++, and MS Visual Studio 2013 installed, to make use off.
I am looking for macros or scripts, I'd prefer a script (python,  perl or php would be a distant second) and I'd prefer a standard-basic library package. What about Windows PowerShell?

Generally speaking, here's my question;

(Q2) How does that wascally web work?! Shouldn't I be able to "View page source", and see where the text is outputted to. Or use something like Wget and copy the functionality of a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used AutoHotkey to write a small macro-script. The help file included with Autohotkey was more then enough to figure all this out, particularly the intro tutorial. Here's the macro-script I wrote;

```
clipboard =  ; Start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived
Run C:\Users\user303696\Desktop\WrdGenerator\wordGenerator.swf, , max ; opens/runs     file with default program
Sleep, 4500  ; amount of time to wait (exp. 4.5 seconds) before executing the next command
loop, 1 { ; number of times to loop
         Click 833, 405 ; performs a simulated mouse click at x,y postion of mouse. Mouse click action generates a random string of text.
         Click 841, 475 ; performs a simulated mouse click at x,y postion of mouse. Mouse click action copies above text to clipboard.
FileAppend %clipboard%`r`n, C:\Users\user303696\Desktop\WrdGenerator\wordGenerator.swf.txt ; Appends/adds contents of clipboard to a text file, as a list.
        }
```

Thanks goes to "benshepherd" and "Bradley Forney".

Answer (score 1):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) might be useful in this case. You should be able to use something like `ControlClick` to simulate clicking the 'Copy' button on the page, wait a short time (e.g. 100ms), and then use `ClipGet` to get the text on the clipboard. Then you can do whatever you want with it (appending it to a text file is probably easiest).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use a technique like web scraping + ocr to handle this most likely. The page is in flash which is why you're not seeing much in the source code. Flash, if your unfamiliar, works *kind of* like a video file that you can interact with in that it's an embedded file and not done with pure coding. That being said - it's a little tricky to pull this off.

Here are some sites that may help:

- http://www.propublica.org/nerds/item/reading-flash-data
- http://www.intelligentpositioning.com/blog/2009/06/how-does-google-read-flash/
- http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-Flash-based-websites/

You may want to explain why you're aiming to get this information as folks here may have some better ideas to help you accomplish what you're after.